# subclassing generic class in code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, inheritance

In an MVC app I'd like to add error and info messages to my domain models but have them not persist to the database.

Currently I have mapping classes that inherit from EntityTypeConfiguration like this example:

```
public class ComputerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Computer>
```

So I plan to create a generic class to inherit from EntityTypeConfiguration so that I can add Ignore() declarations to all derived classes. Something like:

```
protected class MessagableConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
{
    public MessagableConfiguration()
    {
        Ignore(t => Errors);
        Ignore(t => Info);
    }
}
```

And then inherit from MessagableConfiguration like so:

```
public class ComputerMap : MessagableConfiguration<Computer>
```

I'm not sure how to declare MessagableConfiguration. I tried this:

```
public class MessagableConfiguration<Messagable> : EntityTypeConfiguration<Messagable>;
```

.. which is [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx) ..but I intellisense tells me "parameter Messagable hides class Messagable"

BTW Messagable is the base class that Computers and other classes will derive from.

What is the correct syntax, or am I doing something else wrong. Is there a better way?

Comment: I just discovered that a class that is being mapped to the database with code-first, will not try to make columns from inherited properties anyway. This means there's no need to specifically Ignore() those properties, and therefore no need to make a generic configuration class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like following using a [Type Constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public class MessagableConfiguration<T> :EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T: Messagable
```